# How to get References for all installed Applications on Windows with Java?

Tags: java, powershell, search

I know I can run this PowerShell comand

```
"Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName"
```

and I managed to store the output in an String ArrayList. Now I have the names of all installed Applications but not real references I could launch for example.

```
static List<File> Applications = new ArrayList<File>();
public static void recSearch (String path) {
    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) return;

    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            recSearch(f.getAbsolutePath());
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".exe"))
            System.out.println("Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        }
        else if (f.getName().endsWith(".exe") && f.canExecute()){
            Applications.add(f);
            System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        }
    }
}
```

With this I stored every `.exe` in a File List, not only every Application but every install, uninstall and so on. I can run them from this skript, but e.g. Battlefield 4 is called `bf4.exe` and to run a specific Application I had to know every `name.exe` and not only the Application name.

Now I'd like to know how I can get reference Files like in the Code above, but for every installed Application (namely the ones from the PowerShell command).

Thank you in advance and please ask if my question is unclear, it's my first time asking a question here :)

Comment: I don't know much about powershell, unfortunately, but my guess is that you need a different command, one to get the application names, in your case "bf4" or "bf4.exe" instead of the DisplayNames. I only know Java though, so I'm not sure how to help with that.

Comment: I think not, unfortunately. These are all options:
PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSDrive, PSProvider, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, DisplayIcon, UninstallString, InstallLocation, Publisher, URLInfoAbout, EstimatedSize, HelpLink

And InstallLocation only gives the main folder location. But thank you for helping

Comment: Are you asking if you can find executable paths for installed programs? The installation information doesn't tell you the path and filename of the executable for running the program itself (unless the installer's author went out of his or her way to put it there).

Comment: The executable path would be one way I guess, but a better solution (i.m.o.) would be a file reference like in my code example. It does not necessarily have to be via powershell, if someone has another solution feel free to tell :)

Comment: The executable path would be one way to do what?